# gems with middleman

Tags: ruby, middleman

I'm trying to learn Middleman to create a static site hopefully similar to the CMS that RailsCasts builds in this very clever tree-based navigation episode http://railscasts.com/episodes/162-tree-based-navigation-revised . The content of the site will never change once it's created, therefore I thought it might be best to have it as a static site rather than a Rails app, though I wanted to take advantage of using ruby in development. The rails app uses the ancestry gem in order to create the parent-child relationship with certain pages.

```
rails g scaffold page name content:text ancestry:string:index
```

In the Railscast, the parent-child pages can thereafter be created dynamically, even if the content will be static in the end. I'm not sure if a comparable process can be done with Middleman using the ancestry gem. Although I read the docs, I've never created a Middleman app before. I've initiated the app but now it's just a bunch of empty folders.  Any tips how you might go about this? I generally need a lot of guidance when trying something new and, given the paucity of middleman tutorials, would appreciate as much detail as you could provide.

Update

\

Note, ancestry gem stores the parent child information in a string on the database for each entry `ancestry: "1/2"`

Update

One of the problems I see is that, to use Ancestry in Rails, I have to use `has_ancestry` in a class that's a subclass of Active Record. Since there's no db in middleman, it seems impossible, but I'm wondering if the data's included in a yaml file, is there a way to use has_ancestry somehow in a class that doesn't subclass Active Record

```
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :parent_id, :content, :name

  has_ancestry
end
```